# Use React Native class in Android Native project

Tags: android, react-native

I have a medium-big Android and iOS app, currently developed respectively in Android Native (Java) and iOS Native (Swift). I am approaching React Native in order to use it to share *some* code between the two apps, since I can't afford to remake the whole project in React Native in one go.

The plan is to start with some classes: a manager that accesses all our endpoints, some managers, some datatypes. I don't wanna share view for now, because they USE those shared code and I'd have to maintain those managers in three projects.

Is there a way to access React Native classes, that are *not* views (Android Activities/iOS ViewControllers), to Android Native?

I tried https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps and it works, but this looks like a glorified WebView, where the code in the React Native is obscured. If, in the React Native code, I had some plain class, example:

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';


class Adder {
    add = (value) => {
        return value + 10;
    }
}


export default Adder;
```

is there any way I can call *in Java* this code? :

```
int value = new Adder().add(1); // Value == 11
```

Am I using the wrong tool to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experience with Extensions (iOS) and Activities (Android) I think your intent is not really fitting to React Native. React Native is always based on a screen, a ViewController in iOS and an Activity in Android. The whole lifecycle of React Native is inside this Screen and RN is taking care to display the content. When you are inside a RN screen you can use all your native functionality with modules and call RN from the native side. It is already complicated to get a return value from a call from native to RN (not vice versa), so your way of integrating it would probably make it hard for you, even if you circumvent all the logic for displaying the screen.

Having this idea in mind, you can easily exchange single Screens in your app with a (new) RN screen. You call them by startActivity (Android) or presentViewController and alike (iOS) and put all the corresponding logic in RN with possible interaction with some old native code.